# grails async bootstrap

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

Is it possible to use a service asynchronously in the grails bootstrap class?
I am trying to do the following in grails-2.0.4 and the grails-executor-plugin, but only the first log message appears:

```
class BootStrap {

def myService

def init = { servletContext ->

    log.info("Bootstrapping")

    runAsync {
        log.info("Doing myService async ")
        myService.doSomething()
    }

}
```

There is no error message, just no output from the second log statement.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How about starting a thread ? I remember that I've done this in a project but i don't remember if i used class services or not ?

Comment: Yeah! Good idea: I tried the following: def th = Thread.start {
      log.info("Autowarming Imprints async")
  myService.doSomething()
  }

Comment: Yes, it is working - see my code above in the comment! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `runAsync` closure - it is not the right place for it. You can use closures like `production` and `development` here for different environments:

```
class BootStrap {

def myService

def init = { servletContext ->
    log.info("Bootstrapping")
    development {
        log.info("Doing myService async ")
        myService.doSomething()
    }
}

class MyService {
    def doSomething() {
        runAsync {
            // executed asynchronously
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WolfWetzel I've updated my answer. `runAsyc` doesn't work in Bootstrap because it is not extended. Only domains, controllers and services are extended. Check my solution and do not start you own threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot - your suggestion is working. I put the runAsync-Closure in my service class and I am fine with this!