# Reading TCP raw data and send it to ActiveMQ

Tags: grails, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to write an application that reads tracking data from fixed unit controllers that send bytecode and process the data then write to a database. I want to use grails 3.0.4, ActiveMQ, Apache Camel. If I send the data from the controllers straight to ActiveMQ I get a DataType Error and suggestions where that I should use apache camel to receive and then route the messages.

I do know know how to setup apache camel in a grails project. Can anyone help with the steps that are needed to setup Apache Camel to read raw data from a tcp in grails 3.

Comment: Is this of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090254/grails-running-a-tcp-thread-on-background/24200707#24200707

Comment: Thanks Lalit, I had looked at it before but it seems its based on Grails 2.x or below and it works fine but I am using Grails 3.0.4 which is based on spring boot and uses gradle. They changed quite a lot of things in this version and normal configs seem not to be working anymore without a how-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I implemented my solution:

```
In build.gradle under dependencies add the following dependencies depending on the components you want to use as follows.

runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-groovy:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-stream:2.15.3" //runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-netty:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-netty4:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-spring:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.15.3" runtime "org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:5.11.1" runtime "org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:5.11.1"

Create a route that extends RouteBuilder as follows:

class TrackingMessageRoute extends RouteBuilder { def grailsApplication

@Override
void configure() {
    def config = grailsApplication?.config
    //from('netty4:tcp://192.168.254.3:553?sync=true&decoders=#decoders&encoder=#encoder').to('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue')
    from('netty4:tcp://192.168.254.3:553?serverInitializerFactory=#sif&keepAlive=true&sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false').to('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue')
    from('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue').bean(MimacsMessageListener.class)
}

}

Configure a Camel Context in BootStrap.groovy. You can use SpringBeans in resources.groovy if you want

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry) camelContext.addComponent("activemq", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("failover:tcp://localhost:61616")) camelContext.addRoutes new TrackingMessageRoute() camelContext.start()
```

NB. I left out certains part of code that do not affect this answer. If you have these then you ar good to go.